# How do I add OpenGL to a project using CMake?

Tags: opengl, cmake, include, dynamic-linking

I followed this documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenGL.html) and wrote the code below in my CMakeLists.txt...

```
if(NOT OPENGL_FOUND)
    message("there is no OpenGL!")
endif()
```

...to try to figure out how to add OpenGl to a project using CMake.  The message keeps popping up which means the system doesn't have OpenGL.  How do I add it to the system?

Comment: Precise error message please. There are plenty reasons of `message keeps popping up which means the system doesn't have OpenGL`.

Comment: It's not an error, just the "there is no OpenGL!" message I wrote in the code.  I just have no idea how to get CMake to link OpenGL.

Comment: It should be message from `find_package(OpenGL)` call. This is how `findXXX.cmake` CMake modules are used.

Comment: Okay, I tried find_package(OpenGL) and there are no more errors.  I didn't get any errors from target_link_libraries(myProject OpenGL) either, but it's still not linked.

Comment: Please, **edit question post** with your new code and description of your new problem.